# Embedded chat does not persist when navigating

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to get the embedded chat plugin to continue with the user throughout the site's domain and sub-domain. From what I can find, this is already a feature and I just need to include `window.embedded_svc.settings.storageDomain = "domain.com";`

However, the chat is not even able to continue on other pages within the same domain. The site has version 5.0, so it is updated.

Does anyone know how to fix this?